# How to retrieve data from netcdf when latitude/longitude are in 2 dimensions using R/Python?

Tags: python, r, data-analysis, netcdf, data-extraction

My NetCDF file has latitude defined in 2 dimensions i.e. "X" & "Y", similarly longitude. Any variable(eg. "var") has axis "X" "Y" "T" and dimensions "time" "latitude" "longitude". I am not able to retrieve all the values from a variable. Here's what I tried:

```
# get longitude and latitude
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"longitude")
nlon <- dim(lon)
#nlon = int [1:2] 357 342
head(lon)

# get longitude and latitude
lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"latitude")
nlat <- dim(lat)
#nlat = int [1:2] 357 342
head(lat)

print(c(nlon,nlat))

tim <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")

nc.get.var.subset.by.axes(ncin,"var",axis.indices = list(X =nlat, Y = 1, T=1:dim(tim)))
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question that really wants a little more data, but being ncdf, would probably be huge. That said, you might want to try [tidync](https://ropensci.org/blog/2019/11/05/tidync/) to get a sense of things inside.